UI layout analysis algorithm
I want to analyze the UI layout based on Screen Saving Image. Especially, I want to get the video stream layout of Zoom&Teams App, such as if the layout is single video stream, 2 video streams, or others.
The video conference meeting software has many different video layouts based on how many users attend the conference.
